# How do I set up assistant shortcut suggestions with actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE?

Tags: android, app-actions

So I'm just wondering why my code isn't working. How do I give AppShorcutIntent a specific intent with an action and data and stuff like that?

This is my code so far:

```
            val appShortcutIntent = AppShortcutIntent.builder()
                .setIntentName("actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE")
                .setPackageName("com.app.name")
                .setIntentParamName("feature")
                .setIntentParamValue("")
                .build()
            shortcutsClient.lookupShortcut(appShortcutIntent)
                .addOnSuccessListener { shortcutLookupResult ->
                    if (shortcutLookupResult.isShortcutPresent) {
                        shortcutsClient.createShortcutSettingsIntent().addOnSuccessListener { intent ->
                            requireActivity().startActivity(intent)
                        }
                        return@addOnSuccessListener
                    }
                    val signalShortcut = AppShortcutSuggestion.builder()
                        .setAppShortcutIntent(appShortcutIntent)
                        .setCommand("feature on")
                        .build()
                    shortcutsClient.createShortcutSuggestionIntent(signalShortcut).addOnSuccessListener { intent ->
                        requireActivity().startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
                    }
                }
```

I have tried so many different things and none of it seems to want to work the way I want. I know the question doesn't have anything specific as the parameter value but no matter what I set the param value too it still just doesn't get recognized as a unique intent when I use the shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The in-app promo library API doesn't deal with Android intents.  It deals with Assistant's [built-in intents](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents), which are an entirely different things (even though they are both called "intents").  In the example you copied, it refers to the BII called [OPEN_APP_FEATURE](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature).

By using this API, you are telling Assistant how to create a shortcut that launches the app using a BII that it is already configured to handle.  This BII is important because it carries the ability to recognize natural language queries associated with it.  Android intents don't have that context.

Comment: So after adding a shortcut with OPEN_APP_FEATURE, how do I get it to open the feature I want it to open? I can get it to open my app but I'm not sure how to get it to open a specific feature when defining the shortcut through AppShortcutIntent.builder().

Comment: You have to write code to detect the incoming BII and route the user to the feature you want.  The shortcut won't do that for you.  Shortcuts are just configuration used by Android and Assistant to know how you would like your app launched. You have to provide the implementation that decides what to do after that launch.

Comment: Okay thank you very much I'll mark this as solved!